# Get sentences with regular expressions in c++

Tags: c++, regex

I need to get sentences with regex from String with word "walk". Now I am trying just to get sentences

```
std::string s ("Hello world! My name is Mike. Why so serious?");
std::smatch m;
std::regex e ("^\\s+[A-Za-z,;'\"\\s]+[.?!]$");   // matches words beginning by "sub"

while (std::regex_search (s,m,e)) {
    for (auto w:m)
        std::cout << w << "\n" ;
}
```

And this doesn't work.

Comment: The start and end of string match are probably what's tripping up your regex. Unusual to suggest links, but take a look at https://regex101.com/, which is a terrific regex building tool.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from start and end of the string in regex, you are forgetting to update the 's' with the suffix.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string s ("Hello world! My name is Mike. Why so serious?");
    std::smatch m;
    std::regex e ("\\s?[A-Za-z,;'\"\\s]+[.?!]");

    while(std::regex_search (s,m,e))
    {
            std::cout << m.str() << "\n" ;
            s = m.suffix();
    }
    return 0;
}
```